# Realm DB. Update two separate default instances? *FLOWCHART*

Tags: android, multithreading, realm

I am using Realm DB for my Android Project, and I have a problem. I create a default instance of my realm on the Application level, and I use that default instance for 2 threads, separately. So when I create an object in the default instance of the first thread, how am I supposed to copy it to the second thread's realm? The first thread is MainActivity and the second is WidgetService?
I tried `realm.refresh()` , but it didn't work.

Heres the flowchart as i understand it:
[image]

Comment: `realm.refresh()` should work.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#auto-refresh), you'll have to call `waitForChange()` on the realm on the background thread:

> If you get a Realm instance from a thread that does not have a Looper attached, then objects from such instance will not be updated unless the waitForChange() method is called.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply! Both threads (main/UI thread and service thread) seem to have a Looper attached. What do you mean by background thread? Btw some additional info: The service thread is`RemoteViewsService` class, started by `appWidgetProvider` (BroadCastReciever, running on the main thread).